# guardar dato de variable sin refrescar pantalla

Tags: script

tengo este código donde presiono un botón y cambia de estado y color "Ocupado" y "Desocupado " pero no logro guardarlo en la base de datos el valor ya que me refrescar la pantalla y no realiza el el cambio lo que quiero es depuesto mostrar esto en otra pantalla independiente como el estado de las cabinas mi primera pregunta a

```
introducir el código aquí
```

```
<!doctype html>





<script>
    var colores  = ['red','green'],


    index = 0;

        function cambiarColor() {


color.innerHTML=color.innerHTML=="Ocupado"?"Desocupado":"Ocupado";
color.style.backgroundColor = colores[(index++ % colores.length)];

        var valor = document.getElementById("color");


        }



</script>


</head>

<body>



<p><h1 id="color" name="color">estado</h1></p>  

<button style="width:100px; 
height:40px;"  type="submit" name="est" id="cambiar" onclick="cambiarColor()" >Estado</button> 





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el boton es el tipo submit, tienes varias soluciones, te explico dos:

1. Cambiar el tipo de boton a button

```html
<button style="width:100px; height:40px;"  type="button" name="est" id="cambiar" onclick="cambiarColor()" >Estado</button>
```

2. Hacer un prevent default para que no ejecutre la funcion por defecto de submitir

```html
   var colores  = ['red','green'],


    index = 0;

        function cambiarColor(e) {
    
    e.preventDefault()
    
color.innerHTML=color.innerHTML=="Ocupado"?"Desocupado":"Ocupado";
color.style.backgroundColor = colores[(index++ % colores.length)];

        var valor = document.getElementById("color");


        }
```

Comment: muchas gracias pero como obtengo el valor y guardarlo en la base de datos al presionar el botón ya que si coloco un alert me muestra el ocupado o desocupado y sin el submit nose como hacerlo gracias

Comment: deberias hacerlo con ajax

Comment: eso no se hacerlo me puedes orientar esoty buscando info pero me enrredo en algunas cosassi tienes tiempo

Comment: @rodrigoaguero hoy ya no puedo mañana con mucho gusto te envio ejemplos de como hacerlo

Comment: muchas gracias master saludos